# Loop counter when rendering with {{render}}

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a list of posts that I render in a loop.

```
{{#each post in posts}}
  {{render "post" post}}
{{/each}}
```

Now, in the `post` template, I would like to access the index of the post in order to output "post 1", "post 2" and so on. How can I achieve that?

I tried accessing `contentIndex` from each `PostView` but that property is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside of your post template you can use `{{_view._parentView.contentIndex}}` to access the index, it's zero relative. Like this sample [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/8eXWr/).

Other alternative can be wrap your posts content in a new object with the index. Like this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/2Mbxf/)